# PHP Looping using foreach does not add values

Tags: php, foreach

I have an array created from a csv file and the relevant code is:

```
foreach($data1 as $key => $val){
 $data[] = ['country' => $val['Country Name'], 'iso_code' => $val['ISO2'],'phone_code' => $val['Phone Code'],'continent' => $val['Continent'],'capital' => $val['Capital'],'time_zone' => $val['Time Zone in Capital'],'currency' => $val['Currency']]; // so on and so forth.
}
//print_r($data);
```

I get array in the following key->value pair:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [country] => Afghanistan [iso_code] => AF [phone_code] => 93 [continent] => Asia [capital] => Kabul [time_zone] => Asia/Kabul [currency] => Afghani ) [1] => Array ( [country] => Albania [iso_code] => AL [phone_code] => 355 [continent] => Europe [capital] => Tirana [time_zone] => Europe/Tirane [currency] => Lek ) [2] => Array ( [country] => Algeria [iso_code] => DZ [phone_code] => 213 [continent] => Africa [capital] => Algiers [time_zone] => Africa/Algiers [currency] => Dinar ) [3] =>
```

.......so on..

I am trying to insert the values in my DB table using following code:

```
$conn->beginTransaction();
$sql = "INSERT INTO countries (country,iso_code,phone_code,continent,capital,time_zone,currency) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
try {
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
foreach ($data as $v){
 $stmt->execute(array_values($v));
}//end foreach
$conn->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
}//end catch
$stmt->closeCursor(); 
$conn = NULL;
```

The data is not getting inserted nor do I get any error. It is something wrong that I do with my foreach loop?? Unable to identify reason for same. I am a php Newbie.

Comment: Check the database you're are inserting into - make sure that the data types match. It won't work if you have a column in your database set to hold TIMESTAMPs , and you are trying to enter city names, etc.

Comment: try to insert echo $e->getMessage() after this line } catch (PDOException $e) { and write here what it outputs.

Comment: can you echo $stmt and share?

Comment: @IuriiDrozdov Oops!! I had the error catching code and i removed it accidentally. The error is DB column: SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'phone_code' at row 1. the phone_code is 3 digit number and i tried using both INT(5) and Varchar(5)..but still getting error.

Comment: @IuriiDrozdov Thank you for pointing out my missing  error catch message. I am using utf8_general_ci and i solved it. Thanking you once again. Newbie mistakes.

Comment: Keep using a text type - phone "numbers" are not numbers in a database/programming language sense. If you try and store them (fully/partially) as integers, you run the risk of loosing leading zeros - _numbers_ don't have those.